# How to get a HTML select element to display a differenct value when an option is selected than is shown in the dropdown list?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, html-select

For Example I am using a dropdown list of countries with telephone codes shown here: 
[Dropdown list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMmsw.png)

When I select an option the whole country and number is displayed, but I would rather just the number code be displayed. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two dropdowns for this. One with the values to show and the other with the values to select. Then synchronize both with javascript.

https://jsfiddle.net/81nbvtLx/7/

With jQuery you can use:

```
$('#sel2').change(function() {
    $('#sel1').prop('selectedIndex', $(this).prop('selectedIndex'));
});
```